# MVC3: How to Post a Form that contains partial views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, razor, jquery-validate, partial-views

Tools: MVC3, jQuery Unobtrusive Validation, Razor, VS 2010

I am developing an MVC2 project that enables users to request services. I have placed information common to all forms in partial views, which are strongly typed to their own models. Each partial view has its own controller. The partial views are rendered in the main container page. I have unobtrusive jQuery data validation working for all data on the rendered page.

Questions: What is the best way to code a Post that relays all the page data to the server and how can I associate the partial views to their respective models? Is it possible for the controllers for the partial views to handle their own data storage chores? Any good examples somewhere? Or, is this architecture flawed and I should rethink?

Thanks in advance,

Arnold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not at all, sounds nicely broken up and easy to test.  First off, make sure the forms are well set up with the right action, method, etc. in HTML.  So then to post the whole page you could do something like this:

```
var savePage = function () {
    $('form').each(function (formIndex, formElement) {
        var f = $(formElement);
        $.post(f.attr('action'), f.serialize(), successfulFormPost);
    });
};

var successfulFormPost = function (data) { ... };
```

Now, if your MVC view looks something like this:

(Notice the naming convention for the name attribute).  Then you can make your controller for that form take in a strongly typed parameter that matches the view's @Model:

```
public class SomeModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class SomeController : Controller {
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel someModel) {
        // use someModel.Id, someModel.Description here
    }
}
```

I did that HTML a little more manually, but I'm just proving a point about binding and linking up HTML POST with controller actions.  I'll leave it up to you to bring in unobtrusive validation by using the Html.TextBox type syntax.  Just remember to set the name attribute of your input fields according to how the default binder works:

http://www.asp.net/mvc

That's a great source for all these fundamentals.

Comment: Thanks, Milimetric. I've done some $.post functions, but I'm just learning. What purpose does "successfulFormPost = function()" serve? Does it display an alert or perform a redirect? It looks like savePage collects all the form elements and their indexes, then $.post. Would the controller action reveive a FormCollection? Is the controller action specified in: f.attr('action')? Thanks!

Comment: @Milimetric. Wow. I've been playing around with this and, sure enough, I'm seeing my partial view get posted to its [HttpPost] ActionResult. I'm receiving it as a FormCollection and I do see the entered values buried within the collection object. Powerful stuff. Now, I have to mine that data out of the collection. I discovered that I have to place my @Html.Action("Create", "MyPartialView") outside the form on the main container page. But when I do that I lose unobtrusive validation, which was working when my partial view was not contained within a form and was nested on the main page.

Comment: @Arnolld, To your first comment: successfulFormPost can do whatever you need as long as you remember that it'll be executed after each successful form post.  The savePage function actually just loops through each form and posts each one individually.  The controller action is specified in your HTML with something like <form action="@Url.Action(...)" method="POST"> ... </form> or equivalent Html.BeginForm type call.

Comment: @Arnold, To your second comment: On the controller side you can receive the posted data as a strongly typed object.  I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean.  @Html.Action would just spit out the HTML for a link, so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @Milimetric. I'm following what you are saying. @Html.Action("Create", "RequestorInformation") renders the partial view. I was nesting that code within the form on the main page. However, I hit a problem because my partial view was also using a form, and nested forms disrupted the unobtrusive jquery validation. So my first idea was to remove the form in the partial view and let the main page handle validation for all of the elements; and that did work. It seems to be a matter of lining up all the dominoes just right.